# give apache ID permissions to list and CRUD files as OS users

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, sudo

I wasn't sure if this question belongs here or on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com). I can move it there if needed.

In any decent Apache configuration, Apache will run as its own ID; `www-data` for example. And this ID will **not** have permissions to list and [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) files as other OS accounts. This is by security design.

I want to be able to, somehow, have Apache list or CRUD files as another OS account. For example, listing files in the account's home directory or creating a new text file in the account's home directory.

I know one solution is to use file/folder group permissions but I can't do that because I cannot muck with file/folder ownership or permissions.

I looked into [suEXEC](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/manual60/suexec.html), [suPHP](https://www.suphp.org/Home.html), and [php-fpm](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) but none of them will work because they will run scripts as the owner of the script. In my case I am running commands like `cp` or `mv` as an arbitrary number of OS accounts. The only way I could use these tools is to have a script for each OS account. Or have a script owned by `root` but that doesn't sound secure.

So then I got to thinking about `sudo`. I could give `www-data` `sudo` privileges as the OS accounts.

Example of an entry in the `sudoers` file:

```
www-data ALL = (osAccount1) NOPASSWD: /bin/ls, /bin/mv
www-data ALL = (osAccount2) NOPASSWD: /bin/ls, /bin/mv
```

But this just stinks of risk. I cannot pin-point how or why -- it just feels ugly.

Is there anyway to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know one solution is to use file/folder group permissions but I can't do that because I cannot muck with file/folder ownership or permissions.

The traditional User-Group-Other file permissions (`chmod` `chown` `chgrp`) make that difficult but you can use Access Control Lists to set much more granular permissions in addition to those. The  method varies a bit per filesystem and version but think (re)mounting the filesystem with acl support and use `setfacl` or `setrichacl`  to set additional ACL’s to the existing UGO permissions that will grant your webserver the desired access.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-richacl/

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that too but was hoping to avoid using ACLs too. If I can't find another, more elegant way, I'll end up using ACLs...